# Validate/verify the SharePoint site URL (site collection URL and site(web) URL) are correct without using the SharePoint's sp.js and sp.runtime.js

Tags: jquery, site-collection, site, validation

The main objective is to verify that the given SharePoint site URL (which is read through user input) needs to be verified and validated as correct URL before proceeding further. the verification needs to be done using jquery and not through sp.js and sp.runtime.js methods (_spPageContextInfo.webServerRelativeUrl) and not through regex. One of the method could be call a simple ajax call and if it succeeds means site exists so what could be the other method to verify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use Ajax like this:

```
<a href="/somelink" id="test1">Link1</a> <span id="result1"></span> $.ajax($("#test1").attr("href"), { statusCode: { 404: function() { $("#result1").html("not working"); }, 200: function() { $("#result1").html("working"); } } });
```

as used in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9567482/jquery-check-to-see-if-page-exists) related answer on Stack.